# Wildcard includes

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Is it possible to use wildcards for imports?

For example:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/models/*"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/*"></script>
<script src="scripts/init.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Or is there another best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, but we're [looking into adding it](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/661).

Comment: Great, looking forward to it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

[grunt-glob-html](https://github.com/gevgeny/grunt-glob-html) does what you actually need.